# CSS styling - missing second line of text

Tags: css, html

I'm currently writing a quiz app where the three potential answers are styled with the following css:

```
.answer {
            color               : Black;
            background-color    : Aqua;
            border-radius       : 5px;
            height              : 38px;
            width               : 320px;
            padding             : 5px;
            line-height         : 38px;
            text-align          : center;
    }
```

When the text for the potential answer is longer than 320px, the rest of the text doesn't display.
How could I change this css so that the width remains 320px, but the text wraps so that wide lines
are displayed on multiple lines below one another?

Thanks!

Miktor

Comment: could you create fiddle?

Comment: Agreed, remove the height.

Comment: he is asking about width issue, not height. @miktorcheck my answer

Comment: We do not have enough information: with just the code provided, the text would overflow - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/er349azb/1/  ...there is more going on here

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `height` of `.answer`:

```css
.answer {
  color: Black;
  background-color: Aqua;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id felis arcu. Curabitur eleifend pellentesque gravida. Proin non erat lectus. Etiam dui mauris, commodo a sapien ut, convallis mollis turpis. Nulla pretium eros id risus vestibulum, id viverra lectus tincidunt. Nam vitae condimentum dui, non blandit odio. Nunc ornare elementum turpis nec condimentum. Nulla et commodo tortor, vel eleifend sem. Duis molestie iaculis erat, et facilisis enim.</div>
```

Comment: he is asking about issue with width, not height

Comment: @NabeelKhan OP is asking issue with height, not width.

Comment: @Reddy i guess my english is weak then :) lets ask the op wht he was really asking :D

Comment: This tip helped me fix a different problem: bottom text missing when I use `height: 100%` in my `html` section of CSS. Removing `height` fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You need `word-wrap: break-word;`

This will wrap the extra letters instead of hiding them. (Actually they're not hiding as per your css, they're getting around the corner and not being visible due to surrounding elements probably.

So your css now becomes:

```
.answer {
            color               : Black;
            background-color    : Aqua;
            border-radius       : 5px;
            height              : 38px;
            width               : 320px;
            padding             : 5px;
            line-height         : 38px;
            text-align          : center;
            word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Example at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nabtron/7jmrms3L/1/